# Executing a program on PocketPC Today Items doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, pocketpc

I have the following problem. I am using a DLL to add a new menu item for the Today Item List on a PocketPC 2002. I have tested the written DLL on a Windows Mobile 6.5.3 an it works on there.

On the PocketPC the path contains a space and I guess that I don't escape the string right. Consider the following snippet where the problem occurs:

```
        char commandline[100];
        strcpy(commandline, "\\SDMMC Disk\\Test\\Test.exe");
        STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
        int len;
        int slength = (int)strlen(commandline) + 1;
        len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, commandline, slength, 0, 0); 
        wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, commandline, slength, buf, len);

        PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
        ::CreateProcess(buf, buf, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pinfo);
```

Now I was trying to escape the path to the executable like this:

```
strcpy(commandline, "\"\\SDMMC Disk\\Test\\Test.exe"");
```

But unfortunately this does not work. Did I escape the string in a wrong way?

I'd appreciate any help, thank you.